# Selected text in editor doesn't get deleted when typing

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

When I select text in an `Editor` widget and start to type something the selected text doesn't get delete automatically, instead the typed text is appended at the end of the selected text. This behaves like that only when you have a `ANY-KEY ANYWHERE` trigger in your code.

In my project I can't avoid using `ANY-KEY ANYWHERE` but maybe you have other suggestions or solutions for this problem?

I'm using OpenEdge 10.2B07.

Editor generating code:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE FILL-IN-2 AS CHARACTER 
     VIEW-AS EDITOR
     SIZE 16 BY 1.75 NO-UNDO.
```

Trigger code:

```
ON 'ANY-KEY' ANYWHERE
DO :

END.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely the `ON 'ANY-KEY'` trigger that's causing the problem. Without it, the editor clears the highlighted text. If you must have that trigger there, you'll have to clear the text manually. Add this line to the trigger:

```
FILL-IN-2:REPLACE-SELECTION-TEXT("") IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}.
```

That will clear the highlighted text in the editor when you type something.